# Optimizing React Rendering with Function Partial Application

Tags: reactjs

React components compare props with object reference equality, and when you partially apply a function, you get a new function with a different reference which causes a react component to trigger a re-render every single time.

Has anyone faced this issue?

I have a function that renders a component in a specific tab. And one of the props is `this.setTab.bind(this, tab)` which returns a new function every single time. It would be really cool if there was some kind of immutability helper which allows this to be equal based on the bound value...

Answer (score 2):

I'm pulling this directly from the eslint plugin docs ["jsx-no-bind"](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md), and it mentions one possible solution to reduce the number:

---

A common use case of bind in render is when rendering a list, to have a seperate callback per list item:

```
var List = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.items.map(item =>
          <li key={item.id} onClick={this.props.onItemClick.bind(null, item.id)}>
            ...
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
});
```

Rather than doing it this way, pull the repeated section into its own component:

```
var List = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.items.map(item =>
          <ListItem key={item.id} item={item} onItemClick={this.props.onItemClick} />
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
});

var ListItem = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <li onClick={this._onClick}>
        ...
      </li>
    );
  },
  _onClick() {
    this.props.onItemClick(this.props.item.id);
  }
});
```

This will speed up rendering, as it avoids the need to create new functions (through bind calls) on every render.

Answer (score 0):

If your `render` function relies **only** on data from `this.props` and `this.state`, you can implement the [`shouldComponentUpdate` method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) to compare old and new props and state thus telling React when exactly the handler didn't change, to prevent these unnecessary re-renders.

Take this with a word of caution though: if your logic in `shouldComponentUpdate` is incorrect (so it returns `false` when something actually changed), your component will stop updating. These bugs are hard to find later, so beware. (Use profiler to find out if you really need this specific performance gain.)

Comment: yeah, the problem is that setTab could potentially be bound to a different tab...